# Program exectuion Process and virtual memory

Tags: process, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

So, from my understanding when a program is run by a user it is placed onto memory and the then it is transferred to CPU for execution. CPU does not have direct access to physical memory so it creates logical address and then its mapped with physical address.

How does CPU know when to create the logical address, does CPU know that it is about to receive some instruction thus, prepares a logical address? At what point virtual memory is created?

Answer (score 0):

1. The CPU does have direct access to physical memory. The program is not transferred to the CPU (ignoring caching).
2. The operating system creates and maintains the page tables that do logical to physical address translation. One calls an operating system service to map a logical address range to the process address space.

Comment: Once when program is loaded to RAM, does CPU requests for the data or the OS sends the data to CPU? how is first instruction sent to CPU so it knows how to request other instruction based on first instruction.

Comment: The program loader sets up the virtual address space. As the program starts executing, it triggers [a lot of] page faults because it is still on disk. The pages get loaded when the CPU first tries to access them.